# Firefox 10 - unclickable buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

Has anyone seen this behavior:

I have a couple of HTML buttons used to drive a content rotator:

```
<div id="rotatorControls" class="rotatorControls" runat="server">
    <input name="previous" id="previous" type="button" value="&laquo;" />
    &nbsp;
    <input name="next" id="next" type="button" value="&raquo;" />
 </div>
```

The buttons are activated with a little jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            mcarousel = $("#carouseldiv").msCarousel({ boxClass: 'div.box', height: 100, width: 450 }).data("msCarousel");
            //add click event
            $("#next").click(function() {
                //calling next method
                mcarousel.next();
            });

            $("#previous").click(function() {
                //calling previous method
                mcarousel.previous();
            });
        })
```

In IE this works fine...in Chrome and FireFox 10, the buttons aren't clickable. When I roll my cursor over the buttons, the cursor doesn't change and the buttons don't highlight like other buttons do.

Anyone seen this before and/or have any ideas how to fix this? I've already tried setting the z-index on the buttons, and moving them out of the container div (thinking an invisible element is blocking the click), but neither of those worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I'm using the mCarousel plugin provided by Marghoob Suleman (http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-ms-carousel)

Comment: post a link of a demo page or make fiddle reproducing the error

Comment: Are you sure something is not over your button ? Something with a position:absolute or a higher z-index... ? Can you inspect the button by right clicking on it ?

Comment: It turned out that there was a div stacked over the buttons...I managed to solve it by setting positioning data and a z-index attribute. FMaz008, if you answer the question I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess without the full code, I would suggest checking the relevant js files have loaded correctly for this plugin in Firefox and Chrome. Also it would be worth noting in the question that it is via a plugin not standard jQuery that this functionality is from.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing something from the original implementation:

http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/carousel/index.html

For example the `boxClass: 'div.box'` pointing to the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem yesterday with a late version of Firefox and I found help on this site from Mikey G.

This *may* help if you want to go this route, it worked for me on a similiar issue, also with a slideshow.

Place your functions inside the buttons:

```
<input name="next" id="next" type="button" onclick="$mcarousel.next();" value="&raquo;" />
```

Forgive me if I left out a character or two, still pretty new.

It doesn't seem to be z-index, I've found info that suggests sometimes Firefox has problems with '.click()'